# Javascript : add string to iframe with window.opener form popup

Tags: javascript

I use this code for add string to element of parent windows form popup :

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('myid').innerHTML += 'string';
```

Now I want to add string to element of iframe form popup.Both of iframe and parent is in the same domain. I try this code but not work:

```
parent.myframename.window.opener.document.getElementById('iframeelementid').innerHTML +=  'string';
```

What is wrong? Is there any way to do this?

Thanks for any help.

* UPDATE ***

This is my complete code. Main page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myPopup() {
  window.open( "pop.htm", "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 180px, width = 330px)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="input"><iframe src="frame.html" name="myframe"></iframe> </textarea>

<a href="" onclick="myPopup()">Popup</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and pop.htm:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function insert() {
  parent.myframe.window.opener.document.getElementById('inframe').innerHTML += 'asasasas';
  window.close();
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
            <input type="button" id="insert" onclick="insert()" value="insert" />
</body>
</html>
```

and iframe.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
       <span id="inframe"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We'll need much more information (probably the HTML and javascript) to help you with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use `window.opener`

Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp)

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML +=  'Yor STR';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('iframeelementid').innerHTML +=  'string';
```